# Replace NA's in a numeric column with string label "not significant"

Tags: r, tidyverse

Ï want to replace NAs in certain columns of my data frame that are numeric with a string tag - "not significant". I tried the following but got an error

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_inu <- df_inu %>%
    mutate_at(vars(a, b, c), ~replace_na(.x, "not significant"))
```

A sample data below

```
set.seed(1234)

df_inu <- data.frame(a = sample(c(1:20, NA), 20, replace = T),
                     b = sample(c(1:15, NA), 20, replace = T),
                     c = sample(c(1:50, NA), 20, replace = T))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the newer versions of `dplyr`, the `_at/_all` are deprecated in favor of `across` (though couldn't reproduce the error mentioned by OP using `dplyr - 1.0.7` and `tidyr - 1.1.3`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_inu <- df_inu %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), replace_na, "not significant"))
```

-output

```
df_inu
                 a               b               c
1               16               4 not significant
2                5               8              36
3               12               3               8
4               15               4              32
5                9              15              42
6                5              15              43
7                6              13               2
8               16              10              15
9                4               5              49
10               2               2              38
11               7              14 not significant
12               6              15               6
13              15               8              49
14              14              11              29
15              20               4              32
16              14 not significant              49
17               4              12               8
18               4               3              26
19 not significant               7              17
20               8               9               8
```

---

As mentioned above, if there are errors related to `type` difference (possibly occurring in some versions), convert to `character` before applying the `replace_na`

```
df_inu %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
     ~ replace_na(as.character(.x), "not significant")))
```

Comment: i tried but got this error : Caused by error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't convert `replace` <character> to match type of `data` <double>.

Comment: @Ekow_ababio i am guessing that this is an issue with a specific version.  Can you try the update in my post

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using map_df.

library(tidyverse)

```
df_inu <- data.frame(a = sample(c(1:20, NA), 20, replace = T),
                     b = sample(c(1:15, NA), 20, replace = T),
                     c = sample(c(1:50, NA), 20, replace = T))

df_inu <- df_inu %>% 
  map_df(as.character) %>% 
  map_df(replace_na, 'not significant')

knitr::kable(head(df_inu), 'pipe')
```

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 14 | 21 |
| 20 | 3 | 20 |
| 10 | 8 | not significant |
| 5 | not significant | 19 |
| 3 | 2 | 12 |
| 15 | 1 | 25 |